# how to hide a button inside a jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

i have a problem hiding my button inside a jqgrid here is my code

```
{name: 'FitaCorForApproval', index: 'FitaCorForApproval', width: 75,  
  formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
       return '<input type="button" id="hidebuttonID" style ="width: 75px" 
        value="For Approval" onclick="clickme(' + options.rowId + ')" />'
}
```

thanks

Comment: Hi, it's difficult for me to help you without understanding more about your desired result and what your specific problem is. Consider creating a codepen with an example of your problem. Also, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips about creating good questions.

Comment: sorry for being a beginner.. i have a button inside a jqgrid using that code inside the colModel. how can i hide/disabled that button when there is no data?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your formatter function

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  var showStyle= '';
  if(!cellvalue)
  {
      showStyle="display:none";
  }

  return '<input type="button" id="hidebuttonID" style ="width: 75px '+showStyle+'" 
        value="For Approval" onclick="clickme(' + options.rowId + ')" />'
}
```

Comment: thx for the advise but i already find an answer. i just need to disabled it when the condition meet it